# Are there any deities that personify realms other than the earth or sky?

Tags: myth-identification

Many mythologies have deities whom either personify the earth or sky (e.g. Gaia and Uranus). However, are there any deities that represent other realms, like how Tartarus is the personification of Tartarus? Also, please take note that by "realms", I mean places that are inhabited (e.g. Asgard of Norse mythology, Aaru of Egyptian mythology) and not places such as the sun or moon.

Comment: This is very broad.  The number of cultures with a deity of the forest or of the sea is enormous.

Comment: @Chenmunka Sorry i don't think you get what I mean. By realms, I mean places which are inhabited by specieses in mythology(like my examples on top), not places like oceans and forests because they are parts of the personification of Earth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Hel

[Hel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hel_(being)) personified and rules the "bad" afterlife in norse mythology. In fact, she took her name from [it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hel_(location)). There has been speculation that she as a mythological figure was an invention by Snorri, however, as other sources always talk about figures being "in Hel".

Margaret Clunies Ross says that most poetic contexts are not sufficiently clear for us to distinguish between Hel as a place and Hel as "the personified guardian of that place", and that she and her attributes are "tangliable" personifications. (I'm translating back from a translation of *Prolonged Echoes*, so the quotes are likely not exact).

Comment: Yes, except that Hades the god seem to be the primary holder of the name, while for Hel it is the domain.

Comment: @andejons Are you sure she personified her realm? Idk tbh

Comment: @Gibet "Halja" seems to be her gothic name, and her reconstructed name in proto-germanic.

Comment: @KVickneshvara: I've added a better source which does explicitly says that she does.

Comment: @andejons do you know of any *other* gods like this?

Comment: The Roman god [Orcus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orcus), often represented as a gaping mouth, represented the underworld itself, while Pluto was the god who ruled over it and all the dead.

Answer (score 5):

Tutelary deities:

Tutelary deities that personify or protect places are very common around the world. The Romans had major tutelary deities or their cities, the well-known Capitoline Triad for instance, but also on smaller scale with [Lares Compitales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lares), guardian deities of neighborhoods, and [Genius Loci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genius_loci).

Chinese folk religion is rife with place-bound tutelary deities. Notably, the [Dragon kings of the four seas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_King#Dragon_Kings_of_the_Four_Seas), and the [Chenghuangshen (city gods)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_God_(China)), along with gods or river, mountains, towns, etc. Similarly, the Hindu [Gramadevata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramadevata), as well as numerous others, especially shamanistic and folk religions.

Underworld deities:

The underworld is envisioned in many different ways, but there is usually some deity that serves as it's representative. Examples include: Ereshkigal, Hades, Yama, Satan, Hel, Mictlantecuhtli, Izanami, Osiris, Xibalba, Hine-nui-te-pō, etc.